# Calculate total manufacturing output over a shift for each location

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

We currently have a master table stored in our SQL server with the following example information:

| Site | Shift Num | Start Time | End Time | Daily Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 8:00AM | 4:00PM | 10000 |
| B | 1 | 7:00AM | 3:00PM | 12000 |
| B | 2 | 4:00PM | 2:00AM | 7000 |
| C | 1 | 6:00AM | 2:00PM | 5000 |

As you can see, there are multiples sites each with their own respective shift start & end times as well as a total daily target for the day.

Another table in the DB is populated by users via the use of a PowerApp. This PowerApp will push output values to the server like so:

| Site | Shift Number | Output | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2500 | 3/15/2022 9:45 AM |
| A | 1 | 4200 | 3/15/2022 11:15 AM |
| A | 1 | 5600 | 3/15/2022 12:37 PM |
| A | 1 | 7500 | 3/15/2022 2:15 PM |

This table contains a log of all time-stamped output entries for each site / shift.

What I would like to do is do a daily trend of output vs. target. In order to do so, all output values over a specific shift would have to be aggregated in a `SUM` function for a given shift grouped by the shift day. The resulting view would need to look like this:

| Site | Shift Number | Day | Actual | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3/14 | 9500 | 10000 |
| B | 1 | 3/14 | 13000 | 12000 |
| A | 1 | 3/15 | 8000 | 10000 |
| B | 1 | 3/15 | 10000 | 12000 |

This is easy enough for daytime shifts (group by day and sum the output values). However, if you notice in the master table, Site B / Shift 2 crosses midnight. In this example, I would need to sum values from the previous day 4PM up until 2AM of today. The date grouping would be done by the **Shift End Time**. Here's an example of the problem area:

| Site | Shift Number | Output | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2 | 3300 | 3/15/2022 5:45 PM |
| B | 2 | 2200 | 3/15/2022 8:15 PM |
| B | 2 | 1600 | 3/16/2022 12:37 AM |
| B | 2 | 2500 | 3/16/2022 1:15 AM |

I would need these four rows to be aggregated in the view as one row like so:

| Site | Shift Number | Day | Actual | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2 | 3/16 | 9600 | 10000 |

The values should be listed under March 16th since the end time of the shift occurs then. The values are summated and the target is taken from the daily target master table.

How can I properly calculate these outputs for each shift every day irrespective if it crosses into a new day or not in a view? Or should I go a different route altogether?

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what you want if you provide example data that actually covers the case in question.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore , thanks for your comment. I updated the question to have an example from the area of focus as described.

Comment: @farhandsome I think your sample data has incorrect values, your first result table has sites A and B, however the first table with input from PowerApp only has site A; the dates and totals don't match either.

Comment: Sound like you need something conceptually like `DateAdjust = CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME, Timestamp) > EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.

Comment: You might also need a special case for a shift that ends at midnight, such as Start Time = 16:00 and EndTime = 00:00. Midnight may calculate as the next day, but you likely would want to credit the prior day with the output.